# Javascript functions and IE error addEventListener JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Internet Explorer Last version show a very ugly alert about addEventListener, I was reading some fixes here but in my case I believe the solution is to delete the part of the javascript code giving me problems BUT I am a zero to the left with Javascript.

Here is the code and I am sure this code has 2 or more funtions. The first one is for my drop down menu using also JQuery. But it seems like the last part where addEventListener is maybe is not necessary to make my drop down menu works. I got this drop down menu from a website I buyed pre-made with lots of funtions

```
LMenu=$(".menu>ul>li");LMenu.find("ul").siblings().addClass("hasUl").append('<span class="hasDrop iconoflecha icono-flecha"></span>');LMenuLink=LMenu.find("a").not(".submenu a");LMenuLinkAll=LMenu.find("a");LMenuSubLink=LMenu.find(".submenu a").not(".submenu li");LMenuCurrent=LMenu.find("a.current");if(LMenuLink.hasClass("hasUl")){$(this).closest("li").addClass("hasSub")}LMenuLink.click(function(a){$this=$(this);if($this.hasClass("hasUl")){a.preventDefault();if($this.hasClass("drop")){$(this).siblings("ul.submenu").slideUp(250).siblings().toggleClass("drop")}else{$(this).siblings("ul.submenu").slideDown(250).siblings().toggleClass("drop")}}});LMenuSubLink.click(function(a){$this=$(this);if($this.hasClass("hasUl")){a.preventDefault();if($this.hasClass("drop")){$(this).siblings("ul.submenu").slideUp(250).siblings().toggleClass("drop")}else{$(this).siblings("ul.submenu").slideDown(250).siblings().toggleClass("drop")}}});if(!("boxShadow" in document.body.style)){document.body.setAttribute("class","noBoxShadow")}document.body.addEventListener("click",function(b){var a=b.target;if(a.tagName==="INPUT"&&a.getAttribute("class").indexOf("liga")===-1){a.select()}});(function(){var e=document.getElementById("fontSize"),d=document.getElementById("testDrive"),c=document.getElementById("testText");function b(){d.innerHTML=c.value||String.fromCharCode(160);if(window.icomoonLiga){window.icomoonLiga(d)}}function a(){d.style.fontSize=e.value+"px"}e.addEventListener("change",a,false);c.addEventListener("input",b,false);c.addEventListener("change",b,false);a()}());
```

I have a Fiddle with the javascript code it will be easier to read the code.

https://jsfiddle.net/epo5es5n/1/

EDIT: I really don't know where javascript code starts and ends. I just need it to make the Lmenu works its a dropdown UL LI menu only

Comment: Is really necessary  to vote down? Go drink a beer. If you don't want to help just go somewhere else

Comment: Click the `Tidy Up` button https://jsfiddle.net/epo5es5n/2/

Comment: No error details and a big blob of unformatted code is not the proper way to ask a question here. Create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: @novato Learn more about that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Sorry, you need to try to rework your question so we can more easily help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE browsers up to IE8 do **not** support addEventListener (I'm assuming you meant the latest version *you have* when you said Internet Explorer *Last version*). attachEvent is the IE equivalent (well, not exactly equivalent).

If your target browser is only IE8, you can just replace the addEventListeners with attachEvent calls, but a better option (seeing that you already seem to have jQuery) have be to change these to jQuery .bind (or .on if you have a later version of jQuery)